# django combine to query result and perform query on the combined query result on postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am trying to accomplish a query to determine the number of checkout and checkin in a day for an attendance that is unique to the employee without duplication of checkin and checkout, and picking the latest to be distinct.

In essence is combine 2 query result, and perform a query on the result.

Its much easier explained below.

I have 2 models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)    

class Attendance(models.Model):
    CHECKIN = 1
    CHECKOUT = 2
    ATTENDANCE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (CHECKIN, "Check In"),
        (CHECKOUT, "Check Out"),
    )
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    activity_type = models.IntegerField(choices = ATTENDANCE_TYPE_CHOICES, default=CHECKIN)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I have this 2 queries to obtain the unique CheckIn and CheckOut of the employee in the attendance.

```
unique_employee_attendance_checkin_today = Attendance.objects.filter(company=auth_employee.employee.company.id,
                                    activity_type=Attendance.CHECKIN,
                                    timestamp__date = today).order_by(
                                    'employee_id','-timestamp').distinct('employee_id')

unique_employee_attendance_checkout_today = Attendance.objects.filter(company=auth_employee.employee.company.id,
                                    activity_type=Attendance.CHECKOUT,
                                    timestamp__date = today).order_by(
                                    'employee_id','-timestamp').distinct('employee_id')
```

Assuming I have these records

```
Employee
{"id":1, "employee":"michael jackson",
"id":2, "fullname":"mariah carey",
"id":3, "fullname":"taylor swift"}

Attendance
{"id":1, "employee": 1,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 09:08", 
"id":2, "employee": 2,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 10:13",
"id":3, "employee": 3,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 11:30",
"id":4, "employee": 2,"activity_type": 2, timestamp: "2017-12-05 15:13", 
"id":5, "employee": 3,"activity_type": 2, timestamp: "2017-12-05 18:30", 
"id":6, "employee": 2,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 19:13", 
"id":7, "employee": 1,"activity_type": 2, timestamp: "2017-12-06 08:08"}
```

unique_employee_attendance_checkin_today - will output this result

```
{"id":4, "employee": 2,"activity_type": 2, timestamp: "2017-12-05 15:13", 
"id":5, "employee": 3,"activity_type": 2, timestamp: "2017-12-05 18:30"}
```

unique_employee_attendance_checkout_today - will output this result

```
{"id":1, "employee": 1,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 09:08", 
"id":6, "employee": 2,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 19:13"}
```

1. Question no.1 is here:

I want to combine these 2 queries

```
unique_employee_attendance_checkin_today + unique_employee_attendance_checkout_today
```

and

I want to create a distinct for the employee, it will remove 2 of the records, so the output result will be like this.

```
{"id":1, "employee": 1,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 09:08", 
"id":5, "employee": 3,"activity_type": 2, timestamp: "2017-12-05 18:30"
"id":6, "employee": 2,"activity_type": 1, timestamp: "2017-12-05 19:13"}
```

2. Question no.2 is here:

and then do a query based on the result for activity_type = 1 (CHECKIN) and another for activity_type = 2 (CHECKOUT)

The question is above, which is how can i combine 2 queries result, and perform query on the combine queries based on the above requirements.

Comment: Could you clarify why you are using `created_at` in the query, yet your model only has a field timestamp.

Comment: sorry, i edited it, i'ved changed it to timestamp.

Comment: So, I am still confused. Your checkin example qs has activity_type 2 (checkout)... If I understand correctly you want to the latest of anything per date and employee, and then out of those you want to filter the two different activity_types?

Comment: i edited the example records, hope its clearer (see duplication in id=4&6). there is 2 queries which is unique_employee_attendance_checkin_today + unique_employee_attendance_checkout_today. I want to combine the result, and do another query on that result - which is distinct to the employee_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined query (latest attendance per employee/date regardless of type) could just leave the `activity_type` out completely:

```
unique_employee_attendance_today = Attendance.objects.filter(
    company=auth_employee.employee.company.id,
    timestamp__date = today).order_by(
        'employee_id','-timestamp'
    ).distinct('employee_id')
```

Now you can filter checkins out of that set in a nested query like:

```
Attendance.objects.filter(
    id__in=unique_employee_attendance_today,
    activity_type=Attendance.CHECKIN
)
```

This will only result in a single database query.